# Keras / tensorflow custom layer gradient calculation that requires loop and if

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

My question is about custom gradient calculation. I have a custom layer and could not figure out how to properly program its gradient. This gradient corresponds to a transfer function that is similar to a hard-limiter (or sigmoid with very steep transition): the output is `y=x` if the absolute value `|x| < th` is less than a threshold `th` or `sign(x)` otherwise. So, the gradient `g` is `g=0` if `|x| >= th` or `g=1` otherwise. After searching Web I tried the function _MySignGrad described below. The code runs but I face two problems: 1) I tried to "register" the grad calculation but for some reason it is not called and 2) whenever it gets called I am sure I will get runtime error given the code is potentially wrong. Any hints?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

# training parameters
epochs = 10
batch_size = 3
dim_x = 2
dim_y = 4
N = 100 #half training examples

#define some training data and labels
train_class_0 = np.random.normal(size=(N,dim_x,dim_y)) + 3
train_class_1 = np.random.normal(size=(N,dim_x,dim_y)) - 3
train_data = np.concatenate((train_class_0,train_class_1),axis=0)
output_labels = np.concatenate((0*np.ones(N,),1*np.ones(N,)))

# Define custom function which takes also a grad op as argument:
def ak_py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):
    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'AkPyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+7))
    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    #tf.py_func allows to use a python code as an op
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name, "PyFuncStateless": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

# My custom gradient calculation that is wrong
def _MySignGrad(op, grad):
    threshold = 0.01
    newgrad = grad #ok, I guess I cannot do this
    for i in range(batch_size):
        mask = K.ones((op.inputs[i].shape)) #initialize with 1's
        mask[K.abs(op.inputs[i]) > threshold] = 0 #mas is zero when input is above threshold
        newgrad[i] = grad[i] * mask #zero selected gradient entries
    return newgrad

# function that binds forward and backward pass of tensorflow ops
def myfunc(x, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name, "Myfunc", [x]) as name:
        output_x = ak_py_func(np.sign, #try also square and exp
                            [x],
                            [tf.float32],
                            name=name,
                            grad=_MySignGrad)  # <-- here's the call to the gradient
        return output_x[0]

#Custom layer
class LimiterLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LimiterLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, x):
        return myfunc(x)
    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        return tuple(input_shape)

# Define all layers
l1_input = Input(shape=(dim_x,dim_y),name='l1_input')
l2_flatten = Flatten(name='l2_flatten')(l1_input)
l3_limiter = LimiterLayer(name='l3_limiter')(l2_flatten)
l4_dense = Dense(10, activation='tanh', name='l4_dense')(l3_limiter)
l5_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='l5_output') (l4_dense)
# put it all together, creating model from layers
model = Model(l1_input, l5_output)
print(model.summary())
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data, output_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.3)
```

Comment: The code runs ok without runtime errors:  
Epoch 10/10
140/140 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0183 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0214 - val_acc: 1.0000`  
the problem is that the method is not being called.